# How do I return the list of users registered in firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using firebase in my angular app using angularfire2. I am using firebase auth for authentication of users in my app. Now what I want is to show a user any two users already authenticated my app except the user itself. I can explain you as on Facebook we see friend suggestion. Just like that.

Comment: Is this some sort of admin UI with privileged access to lookup all registered users?

Comment: @bojeil No, I want to show a client some two or three other clients which are using the same app.

Comment: And @bojeil is there a way in **angularfire2/database** of `equalTo: !'any value'`

Comment: Please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593897/firebase-database-query-list-for-not-equal-to

Comment: You can keep track of all users using the app in some database node. You can add their UID in that node everytime they sign in and remove it on signOut. Not sure if this is what you want. You provide very little details.

Comment: Hey @bojeil I am editting my post and providing some more details. Please check out and help.