# Firebase Database query list for not equal to

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am using Firebase in my Angular 4 app using AngularFire2. I have my database structure something like this.

```
{
  "users": {
    "-Kr6HDbj9tMxmxsQ8UnM": {
      "name": "abc",
      "email": "xyz@example.com",
      "uid": "XLTPwGtFYcX6xVHbJGerHxGayT2"
    },
    "-Kr6JBzN_9PZAMctYwt-": {
      "name": "pqr",
      "email": "pqr@example.com"
      "uid": "cdIj8YOncYYiUIEJrb65ynfFcl2"
    },
    ............
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the last two entries of this data structure but exclude the data where uid is not equal to `auth.uid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you changed the datastructure so the key of each user is their uid, like this.

```
{
"users": {
    "XLTPwGtFYcX6xVHbJGerHxGayT2": {
      "...": ".........",
      "...": "........."
    },
    "cdIj8YOncYYiUIEJrb65ynfFcl2": {
      "...": ".........",
      "...": "........."
    }
}
```

Then you could easily access the specific users properties
With the https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

Example

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/"+auth.uid);
ref.once('value')
    .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    // handle read data.
});
```

Comment: Hey Kim, I don't want two entries from whole of `users` data except the pushId in which uid is not equal to `auth.uid`

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You only want the pushId of the user where the uid is not equal to auth.uid?

Comment: Kim You're right, but I want data of that pushId also.

Comment: So you want the last 2 new users where uid is not equal to auth.uid?

Comment: Checkout the post once again. Now suppose that `auth.uid` of user = "cdIj8YOncYYiUIEJrb65ynfFcl2". Now I want data of all the pushId's in users key except data of pushId -Kr6JBzN_9PZAMctYwt- What I'm trying to say if user pqr is signed in I want data of user abc

Comment: I would probably just pull everything out and filter it on the client, I'm not sure if its possible to filter the data before it arrives.

Comment: Kim Can you tell how can we process data on the client side i.e. on front-end

Comment: You get a DataSnapshot, so you can use the forEach https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach. Then you can just filter out your signed in user. The solution is a bit messy though.